# How to upload pure HTML site with TFS build

Tags: deployment, tfs, build, frontend, webdeploy

Our web site solution consists of frontend folder, where pure html/css/js application resides, and an ASP.NET WebAPI backend. I am setting up a TFS build for dev and qa environment.

Currently, I have made WebAPI backend to publish automatically via WebDeploy. Html/js fronend also has a site setup on a target IIS machine where I am trying to deploy to. But WebDeploy only works with ASP.NET sites. What mechanism I could utilize to copy files of fronend to target folder on IIS machine?

Comment: Web deploy works fine with pure content. It doesn't know what kind of site it is. What problems did you have when you tried to use web deploy on the pure content? Also, did you know you can have a project that only contains content?

Comment: The problem with WebDeploy, is that you need a publish profile to have it executed, and publish profiles are created for asp.net projects, and not jsut holders with files. At lease I am not aware of option to webdeploy folder in source control.

Comment: Publish profiles are just MSBUILD project files. Also, what happens if you create an empty ASP.NET project, then add a bunch of content and remove all the code? That's pretty close to a content-only project.

Comment: You would still need to have a .csproj file, which deprecates an entire idea. Frontend developers want to just push files to a folder. As for publish profiles, they are pubxml files, and from what I know, msbuild projects have an extension of .proj.

Comment: MSBUILD projects have whatever extension they want, including .pubxml. Look at one and you'll see. Also, if it's a question of getting the content deployed, I'm sure you can find a way to maintain the .csproj file that the front-end developers are too frightened to use. It's not rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2014/06/deploying-uncompiled-resources-release-management/

I haven't had a chance to test it myself yet.